# Children elements didn't inherit parent data with D3 force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout, selectall

I have created a d3 force layout,and works very well.
My mainly code like so:

```
var nodes = [{id:1, n:'n_1',np:'0'},{id:2, n:'n_2',np:'0'}];//just for demo
//1. set data
var update = svg.selectAll(".node").data(nodes);
//2. enter
update.enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "node")
.call(function(p){
  p.append("svg:image").attr("class", "nodeimage");
  p.append("svg:text").attr("class", "nodetext");
});
//3. exit
update.exit().remove();
```

As is known to us, d3.selectAll(".node").data() is my data. Because the child elements of g will inherit the data from the parent data, `d3.selectAll(".nodeimage").data()` is also my data.Am I right?

In fact, my data nodes is from backend, and the data is updated. For example, some properties like `np` have been changed from 0 to 1. We consider the result is 
`nodes = [{id:1, n:'n_1',np:'1'},{id:2, n:'n_2',np:'0'}]`;

I need to call the function above again. However,`d3.selectAll(".node").data()` is right, while `d3.selectAll(".nodeimage").data()` is wrong now.

The following code will not work well.

```
d3.selectAll('.nodeimage').attr("test", function(d){
    //d.np is a wrong value.
});
```

Any suggestions for me?

Here is my demo of jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/bpKG4/663/

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: There must be something else going on, somewhere in your code where you edit `np`. Could you post the code for a complete example showing the bug?

Comment: @tarulen My dear friend, I have finished my demo on jsfiddle.Please take a look at it.I need your help,Thanks.

Comment: @MoralesBatovski I have put my demo link and I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: Oh,guys,i clarify my problem clearly and the friend tarulen gave me an acceptable answer.Why vote down and close my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange behavior of `d3`. If I understand correctly (which is not granted), `selection.data(...)` automatically transfers data to child elements, unless they already have some data binded.

In your case, it means that you need to copy "by hand" the data to each child:

```
  //select any child node, then:
    .each(function() {
      d3.select(this).datum(d3.select(this.parentNode).datum());
    })
```

NB: in your fiddle, you only set the `xlink:href` in the `enter()` selection: this is wrong, you need to set it within the whole `update` selection.

```
update.selectAll(".nodeimage") 
          .each(function() {
             d3.select(this).datum(d3.select(this.parentNode).datum());
          }) 
          .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
            var img;
            if(d.np == 1){
                img = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1eccef322f0beef11e0e47ed7963189b/?default=&s=80"
            }else{
                img = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a1338368fe0b4f3d301398a79c171987/?default=&s=80";
            }
            return img;
          });
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/cs4xhs7s/1/

Comment: @user1613381 does that help?

Comment: Yes,thank u very much.It works very well.

Comment: @Does Feel free to accept the answer then ;)